# How to make a javascript variable that was changed stay the same after refresh using localStorage with full example

Tags: javascript, variables, refresh, local-storage

I know some people have asked this question before, but I never get it. I'm going to use another question as an example. Say I have a variable that has a value of 1. I click a button that changes it to 2. I refresh, but I want the variable to still stay at 2. Someone in that question answered and said to use localStorage, but I don't get it AT ALL. I tried several times, and it never worked. Can someone please give an example of a complete JS file using it? What I mean is I don't want the answer to just be-
"Use this to set you variable: localStorage.setItem("test", test); and this to get it: 
var test = localStorage.getItem("test");"
I want a full example with all the code. Here's what I'm talking about, except I made this so it doesn't work:

```
<html>
<body onload="getItem()">
  <p id="tt">1</p>
  <button onclick="changeTest()">changetest</button>
</body>
<script>

var test = 1;
localStorage.setItem("test", test);

function changeTest()
{
    test = 2;
    document.getElementById("tt").innerHTML = test;
    localStorage.setItem("test", test);
}

function getItem()
{
    localStorage.getItem("test");
    document.getElementById("tt").innerHTML = test;
}
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`window.localStorage.getItem` *returns* the variable, it does not *import* it, because the variable is already in the script. For example:

`var test = window.localStorage.getItem("test");`

You can also use `window.localStorage.test`, the main difference being that no storage event fires (if I'm not mistaken)

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is in setting the localstorage.test to test=1 on the load of the page each time.

Second in the get function you are not assigning the value of localstorage  to test variable.

this is a working code:

```
         <!DOCTYPE html>


         <html>
        <body onload="getItem()">
              <script>

        var test ;


          function changeTest()
          {
            test = 2;

          document.getElementById("tt").innerHTML = test;
           localStorage.setItem("test", test);   

          }

        function getItem() 
         {
             alert(typeof localStorage.test === "undefined")
       test=  typeof localStorage.test === "undefined" ? 1 : localStorage.test
       alert(test)
        document.getElementById("tt").innerHTML = test; 
         }    
          </script> 
          <p id="tt">1</p>
         <button onclick="changeTest()">changetest</button>

        </body>

         </html>
```